# I can not change a menu to lowercase letters

Tags: android, menu, uppercase, lowercase

**Problem:** I can not change a menu to lowercase letters.

I have a menu as indicated below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionOrdenesMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/item_ordenes"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_carrito"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tituloMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/item_orden"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionGuardarMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/item_guardar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_guardar"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionCancelarMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="@string/btn_cancelar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_eliminar"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

And it is invoked in the following way:

```js
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pedido, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

And the only item that displays text keeps the letters in uppercase even though they are disabled. (`android:textAllCaps="false"`).

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
Thanks